# Where do our example tags come from?

Tags: support, tags, help-center

So, we have two kinds of example tags, from what I can see.  The first is when you ask a new question, before tags are entered, three are provided as suggestions.  For example, today it says (for me) "at least one tag such as (fate monk feats), max 5 tags".  Previously, I've seen (fate monk feats) replaced with stuff like (rules-as-written pathfinder gm-techniques) as a random example I might not actually have ever seen, so I know those tags change, probably frequently.

Then, on the side of the new question page we have, when the tag line is selected, the "How to tag" guidance.  This guidance states, in part: "combine multiple words into single-words with hyphens (e.g. dnd-5e), up to a maximum of 35 characters".  I don't know that it ever doesn't say dnd-5e, but it might.

Do we set these tags?  Are they automatically selected?  If so, how?  Can we blacklist stuff like [game-rec](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) and [just-for-fun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/just-for-fun) to keep them from showing up as a fill-in-the-blank here?

Answer (score 2):

According to [How are "Suggested Tags" chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907), the ones below the tag field are generated by analysing the text of the question as compared to our existing questions.

I haven't found how the one in the sidebar is chosen, but I expect it's something similar but based on all questions we get. That one is there before the asker starts typing, so it's general guidance and can't be text-sensitive.

We don't have any tools for influencing them.

Comment: +1, but I think darkwanderer is asking about the suggested tags that show up *before* the question contains any text. For example, if I hit Ask Question, I see "feats system-agnostic magic". Then, once I start typing a question, the suggested tags change to something more relevant.

Comment: That is in fact what I'm talking about, the ones *in* the tag field.  Good to learn about the other's, though!